# Проблема с API 2.1( переделать из 1.0)

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Не пойму как переделать в API 2.1,
В конструкторе на сайте версия 1.0 высылает, которая при совмещении с кодом для версии API 2.1 не показывает карту.

[image]

Comment: В виджете конструктора карт, который вы вставляете на свой сайт используется версия 2.1. Как я понял из вашего сообщения, то на вашем сайте виджет не работает с другой картой. Если это так, то нужна ссылка на сайт где не работает и я помогу разобраться, что не так.

Answer (score 1):

[Официальная докуметнация](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/update/concepts/update-docpage/)

Там приведены примеры кода для обоих версий API
[image: Пример кода]

Comment: Только мне нужен конструктор а не стандартная карта, своя карта. .... https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/ итд

Comment: @Макс https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/constructor/concepts/About-docpage/ Насколько понятно из примера на сайте, актуальная версия КОНСТРУКТОРА 1.0

Comment: То есть свою карту никак нельзя добавить ?

Comment: @Макс API конструктора и API яндекс карт это немного разные вещи(насколько я понимаю), функционал api конструктора меньше, но имеет UI

Comment: @Макс конструетор вставляет готовую карту, а api карт позволяет работать с этой картой через javascript